# nested mkdir inside directory with spaces

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface

This command:

```
mkdir "watermelon fun"\example
```

Outputs the following:

```
PS C:\Users\Andrés\temp> mkdir "watermelon fun"\example
mkdir : No se encuentra ningún parámetro de posición que acepte el argumento     '\example'.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ mkdir "watermelon fun"\example
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [mkdir],     ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,mkdir
```

Is there a way you can create a nested directory, being one of these a multiple word directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to surround the complete path with quotes:

```
mkdir "watermelon fun\example"
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the Join-Path cmdlet to combine a path.

```
$path = join-path 'watermelon fun' 'example'
New-Item -Path $path -ItemType Directory -Force
```